# use of "From" Clause in SSH config file to find out where a user came from into a host

Tags: ssh

I need to find out if there is an SSH feature called a “from clause” which will record “where” a user who SSHs into the host came from....something useful to audit the SSH connections coming into a host ..... if yes, what would be the syntax to use it in the sshd_config file ?

Answer (score 0):

This information is already stored by ssh in its logs
eg. on Debian :

```
cat /var/log/auth.log |grep ssh
```